# Referencing NuGet packages from multiple sources in same project

Tags: .net, nuget

I want to reference multiple NuGet packages into a C# project, but those packages come from more than one package source. To complicate things, it is possible that 2 packages with the same identifier (and versions) exist in both sources but I want to reference it from an explicit source.

The packages.config file would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="PackageA" version="2.6.9" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="PackageB" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Assuming PackageA exists both in source 1 and source 2, I want it explicitly from source 2, while PackageB is from the default one (source 1). I never want them retrieved from the other source, even if they don't exist anymore in the specified one. I also want this information to be somehow stored as part of the "Enable NuGet package restore" command, as I won't be checking in the "packages" folder into source control.

Is there a way to achieve this mix of packages from distinct sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported. There is no way to specify a particular package source for a particular NuGet package.

You should either use different package ids or copy the required packages to the single package source where you can control which packages are used.

Comment: That's unfortunate... Alternatively, is it possible to use the package version as a complementary identifier for the package? For instance, i know that version "2.6.9-b009" will only exist in one of the sources, can i rely on this to make sure the package will be retrieved from that source and only that source?

Comment: Yes I believe that will work. However I would test it to verify it does indeed work.

Comment: I see. A better solution that comes to mind is the order of package sources listed in NuGet.config under `<packageSources>`, i think that NuGet tries to restore the packages from sources in that strict order.

Comment: You would need to test having them in the NuGet.config. As far as I am aware NuGet will look at all repositories in parallel and wait for the first result to come back from one of those repositories.